# Should you approve edits of a low quality post?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Stumbling over this quite a few times, I see people editing `very-low-quality` questions (most of them OffTopic or DoThatForMe-Stuff with really bad spelling and grammar), to turn them into `not-at-the-bottom-of-very-low` questions, but still worthy of downvoting/closing.

How do you handle such suggested edits? Should you approve them, or reject and flag the question?

Answer (score 4):

I evaluate the edits on their own merits. There is no reason to leave a question broken in one way just because it is broken in another.

And, of course, flag or down-vote as appropriate.

It seems that one of the concerns is that the bad questions get pushed up the queue when they are edited. I would suggest that that might be a good thing, as those questions come under further scrutiny of the community and that might prompt comments or votes which could help the OP improve.

Comment: On the other hand, fixing the grammar and spelling of a low-quality *content* question is rather like rearranging the deck chairs on the *Titanic*. Does it help the WPSE site/community that a question has proper spelling/grammar before it gets closed?

Comment: +1 to answer. Edit might not have saved it, but edit was an attention and effort, which deserves recognition.